# PagedList MVC With JQuery UI Autocomplete Causing Error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete, pagedlist

I'm trying to use JQuery UI Autocomplete on a text box to filter through a Paged List and dynamically update the list so it only shows anything that starts with the value from the filter. However whenever I start typing into the search box I get the following error:

Syntax Error: Unexpected Token <

Here's my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string filter, int currentPage = 1)
    {
        List<string> allEmails = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            allEmails = dataContext.Emails
                .Where(x => x.email.StartsWith(filter))
                .Select(x => x.email)
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            allEmails = dataContext.Emails
                .Select(x => x.email)
                .ToList();

        }
        PagedList<string> model = new PagedList<string>(allEmails, page, pageSize);
        ViewBag.Emails = allEmails.OrderBy(x => x).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        ViewBag.Filter = filter;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here's My view:

```
 @model PagedList<string>
 @using PagedList
 @using PagedList.Mvc

<div id="paginatedDiv">
    <table id="pageinatedTable">
         <tr>
             <th>
                 Email
             </th>
         </tr>
         @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Emails)
         {
              <tr>
                 <td>
                     @item
                 </td>
             </tr>
         }
     </table>

     @Html.PagedListPager(Model,
        (page) => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new
        {
            page,
            pageSize = Model.PageSize,
            filter = ViewBag.Filter
        }),
        PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
 </div>
 @Html.TextBox("search")


 @section scripts
 {
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#search').autocomplete({
                     source: function(request, response)
                     {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                            data: {
                                filter : $("#search").val(),
                                page : '@Model.PageNumber'
                            },

                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(error);
                            }

                        })},
                      minlength: 1
             });

         });
     </script>
  }
```

Is what I'm trying to do here possible? Am I going about it the wrong way? If you need more information let me know.

Comment: I think the ajax function is returning a HTML error which is trying to getting parsed to the function..it will fail because first character will be < in that.. put a break point on the controller and check is it functioning correctly

Comment: Glad to hear that :)..will put it as an answer..mark it is solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax function is returning a HTML error which is trying to getting parsed to the function. It will fail and error out because the first character will be '<' like